# 2n3904 vs. Pn2222A for FM Radio Transmitters

Tags: transistors, transmitter

My question is which is better for transmitting an audio signal on the common 88 - 108 fm band: the common 2n3904 NPN transistor or the PN2222A NPN or are they interchangeable. I have seen a lot of circuits and some have one and some have the other.

[EDIT]

I realized my question was not clear. For the time being I would be fine if you could tell me which of these transistors would be best for [this circuit](http://i1.wp.com/cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/10/kogawa_simplest_transmitter.png?resize=620%2C354).  I know the 2N3904 is used but would the other one be better or could they be interchanged?

Image from http://i1.wp.com/cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/10/kogawa_simplest_transmitter.png

[image: from 1.wp.com/cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/10/kogawa_simplest_transmitter.png]

Comment: They're reasonably interchangeable but both are rather underpowered for this application. There's nothing in this question that can't be answered by consulting the datasheets.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be answered because you haven't provided a schematic and said what function exactly the transistor in question is supposed to perform.  Either of those transistors could be appropriate for some functions in a FM transmitter.